# Как сделать так, чтоб бот создавал канал в категории в моём коде

Tags: python, discord.py, channels

bot.command()
async def createchannel(ctx):
guild = ctx.guild

```
mbed = d.Embed(
    title = 'Succses',
    description = "Канал создан" 
)
if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_channels:
    channel1 = guild.get_channel(channel.id)
    ch = await ctx.send(embed = mbed)
    await sleep(2)
    await ch.delete()
    await channel.set_permissions(ctx.author,speak=True,send_messages=True,read_message_history=True,read_messages=True)

    emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Репорт', color = 0x000000)
    emb.add_field(name = 'Если у вас есть вопрос, задайте его поддержки', value = 'Задаём адекватные вопросы')
    emb.set_footer(icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url, text = "Тех. Администратор Discord - Art")
    emb.set_thumbnail(url = 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/c1/ac/82/c1ac829074cae408a16e17d600af0656.jpg')
    await channel1.send(embed = emb)
```

Answer (score 0):

создать канал в существующей категории можно так:

```
categoty = utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name='имя категории')
channel = await categoty.create_text_channel(name='имя канала')
```

можно писать create_voice_channel или create_stage_channel